# Form select options access desire field from foreign key table in cakephp 3.x.x

Tags: cakephp, relationship, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

In my Project I have items table this contain two foreign Keys locations_id and categories_id. When i add new item, cateogries_id appear categories.name 
in add.ctp : select options (foreign) Key is display Id.  
**I want to appear at location select option locations.city field from location table.**
this is used by cake bake command to my all tables.!
Thanks
[image: My Project Sample image clear!]

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\src\Model\Table\LocationsTable.php
Change Display Field. this is show Id ..
now Change

`$this->displayField('id');` To `$this->displayField('name');` /*name is your field in you table you want to display
[image]